# What does vsync mean?

Tags: graphics-card

In a few games (Osmos and Batman Arkham City are examples) there's a *vsync* item on the video options menu, but I don't know what it does and don't notice any differences when it is on or off.

What is vsync? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vsync stands for [Vertical synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vsync#Vertical_synchronization) and is used to get rid of [tearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing) in games.

Tearing happens when your GPU sends a new frame to your screen, while it is still displaying an older frame. Vsync tries to mitigate the issue by only sending a new frame, when your screen has finished displaying the older frame.